# How to create a chart with X and Y as strings?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want the `X` axis to be a list of job descriptions, and the `Y` axis to be a list of worker names. Something like this:

[image]

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var categoriesX = ["Job1", "Job2", ...];
var categoriesY = ["Dude1", "Dude2", ...];
$(chartId).highcharts({
    // Don't know what kind of chart I should use
    ...
    xAxis: {
        categories: categoriesX,    
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        categories: categoriesY,
        title: {
            text: null,
        },
    }
    ...
}
```

But then, how can I render the values using `(x,y)` notation if `x` and `y` are strings. Is it posible? Is there a better approach?

#### Note:

I know I can do this using some kind of dynamic HTML table, but I have other charts in the same page and I want this one to be a chart too.

---

[Cross-post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2430/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-gr%C3%A1fico-teniendo-x-e-y-como-cadenas) on Stack Overflow in Spanish

Comment: what do you want the end result to look like?

Comment: @BarbaraLaird I think a point on the X,Y position will suffice for now

Comment: Your x and y values need to be the array index of the category to which they belong. So if you want a point at "Job2, Dude1", your data values are [1,0]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the answer was giving to me from the [answer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/2457/100) by [Javier Cárdenas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/353/javier-c%C3%A1rdenas) on SO in Spanish.

Using a chart of type `heatmap`:

[image]

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tm8aw4j/2/).